# How does getting the highest value work with Logic Programming with AND, NOT and >

Tags: racket, logic-programming

This is about **Logic Programming** from **Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs**

It's a simple problem of understanding how to get the highest value.

This a sample database:

```
((is-student Anna)
(is-student  Bart)
(is-student  Charlie)
(is-student  David)
(is-student  Eddy)
(is-student  Fanny)

(has-points Anna    73)
(has-points Bart    84)
(has-points Charlie 65)
(has-points David   34)
(has-points Eddy    85)
(has-points Fanny   70))
```

I understand the following code is giving a summary of the students with their points:

```
;;; Query input:
(and (is-student ?student1)
       (has-points ?student1 ?points1))

;;; Query results:
(and (is-student fanny) (has-points fanny 70))
(and (is-student eddy) (has-points eddy 85))
(and (is-student david) (has-points david 34))
(and (is-student charlie) (has-points charlie 65))
(and (is-student bart) (has-points bart 84))
(and (is-student anna) (has-points anna 73))
```

The same with combinations with AND & OR are ok to understand. It's mostly working out the combinations and filter out the results.

I'm having difficulties understanding the code below to **get the student with the highest points**. It looks simple, yet I don't understand how the combination with AND & NOT & "> points2 points1" provides the biggest value(points)?

This is what I get when I run it (in DrRacket) to get the student with the highest points:

```
;;; Query input:
(and (is-student ?student1)
       (has-points ?student1 ?points1)
       (not (and (is-student ?student2)
                 (has-points ?student2 ?points2)
                 (lisp-value > ?points2 ?points1))))

;;; Query results:
(and (is-student eddy) 
     (has-points eddy 85) 
     (not (and (is-student ?student2) 
               (has-points ?student2 ?points2) 
               (lisp-value > ?points2 85))))
```

How does comparing the negation of second list with the first one work?
Is each answer/line from the first result compared with each line of the second AND?
I don't know how to read/interpret the code and why this gives what we were searching for?

Any help understanding how this gives the highest value would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

PS: I'm not a native English speaker, I apologize for any grammatical or spelling errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that I could have an interpretation of this: I have a student1 that has a point of point1 **and** there **not** existed a situation that there exists a student2 that has a point of point2 **and** point2 is bigger than point1. 
and the bold **and**, **not** matches the code perfectly.
Hope this could help you, and I am not a native English speaker either: )

Comment: Thank you YoarkYANG!, It seems I forgot to thank you! Sorry for the delay!